# Limit of an infinite series as limit of sequence of partial sums.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why is the limit of an infinite series the same as limit of sequence of partial sums?

Context: I was solving a question to find the limit of an infinite series (real analysis). One method stated that it is equal to the limit of sequence of partial sums. I did not understand why.

Edit: **sequence of** partial sums

Comment: That's by definition (otherwise the "sum of an infinite number of terms" has no meaning).

Comment: @Siddarth it might help us answer your question if you tell us a bit more: what made you think of this question in the first place?  What do you think that the limit of an infinite series *should* be, if not the limit of its partial sums?

Comment: It should be "sequence of partial sums" rather than "series of partial sums".

Comment: why the downvote? It is a very good question to understand how "modern" mathematics works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *value* of a series (any series is generally defined as an addition of infinite terms, otherwise it will be a sum) is generally *defined* as the value of the limit (if exists) of the sequence defined by it *partial sums*, that is

$$\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=m}^n a_k$$

Many mathematicians use the symbol "$:=$" to mean: the left hand side is defined to represent the right hand side.

Here $\sum_{k=m}^n a_k$ is a partial sum because the series is partially added up to just the $n$-th term.

If we set $x_n:=\sum_{k=m}^n a_k$ (observe the use of the symbol "$:=$") then the value of the series is equivalently defined to be the value (when it exists) of the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$[*].

[*] If $m> 0$ (if the series start with an index distinct of zero) then the sums of the kind $\sum_{k=m}^na_k$ are defined to have value zero when $n<m$. This is a convention called [the empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum).